# How to upgrade to latest version of java JDK using homebrew cask?

Tags: java, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I have been following these instructions to install the latest java jdk:

```
www.lonecpluspluscoder.com/2017/04/27/installing-java-8-jdk-os-x-using-homebrew/

brew cask install java
```

This works great, but when a new version comes out, how do I make sure I can upgrade to that version and ensure that old versions of the jdk are not sitting around on my system?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, Homebrew does not uninstall old versions of a formula, so over time you will accumulate old versions.

The [cleanup](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#how-do-i-uninstall-old-versions-of-a-formula) - `brew cleanup` command will remove outdated installed package versions.

Comment: Just to clarify, so whenever I discover a new version, I should run brew cask update followed by a brew cleanup?

Answer (score 17):

Warning: Calling `brew cask reinstall` is deprecated! Use brew reinstall instead

`brew reinstall java`

Answer (score 9):

```
brew cask reinstall java
```

This command will uninstall old version of jdk and install the latest version

Comment: It fails with `Error: Unknown command: cask`

Comment: @Boris This is due to the fact that `brew cask` is no longer a `brew` command. Use `brew <command> --cask` instead. If that doesn't work you may also try just 'brew reinstall java'

Answer (score 2):

To upgrade the sub-version of java i.e from `11.0.8,10` to `11.0.9.1,1`, use the following command.

```
brew upgrade --cask adoptopenjdk11
```

Answer (score 1):

As of April 2023,

Install java (`openjdk`) using `brew install openjdk`

Then while you have `openjdk` installed, running `brew install openjdk` in the future, upgrades java to the latest openjdk version (provided by homebrew).